# Need to retrieve top 3 vendors by total amount, per category - subcategory

Tags: mysql, sql, select, aggregate, sequel

I have this db table: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e1dd38e/7

I am trying to query it so it goes thru each category, returning each subcategory's top 3 vendor's, ordered by their total of spend (sum(amount)), the vendors outside of the top 3 will be summed up as a total and be included as "Others"

Also including total amount for category and subcategories

I appreciate any help, struggling on this one

Expected outcome would be:

```
Paper 515.54
    Napkins 314.99
        Paper LLC 110.49
        Dunder Mifflin 70.99
        Brawny 60.02
        Others 73.49
    Towels 200.55
        Acme LLC 52.01
        Michigan Paper 41.23
        Cascades LLC 40.55
        Others 66.76
Food 205.54
    Apples 178.76
        Orchards LLC 97.10
        Northstar Orchard 41.23
        Apples LLC 40.43
    Pizza 26.78
        Dominos 16.53
        Pizza Hut 10.25
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the new requested requirement, *Also including total amount for category and subcategories*, you may use a sum window function within the provided query in the previous answer as the following:

```
WITH purchases_cat_sum AS
(
  SELECT *,
         SUM(amount) OVER (PARTITION BY category) category_total_amount,
         SUM(amount) OVER (PARTITION BY category, subcategory) subcategory_total_amount
  FROM purchases
)
SELECT category, category_total_amount,
       subcategory, subcategory_total_amount,
       CASE grp WHEN 'Others'
         THEN CONCAT(COUNT(*),' ', grp)
         ELSE grp
       END AS vendor,
       SUM(sum_amount) AS total_amount
FROM
(
  SELECT category, category_total_amount,
         subcategory, subcategory_total_amount,
         vendor, SUM(amount) sum_amount,
       CASE 
         WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY category, subcategory ORDER BY SUM(amount) DESC) <=3
         THEN vendor
         ELSE 'Others'
       END AS grp
  FROM purchases_cat_sum
  GROUP BY category,category_total_amount, 
           subcategory, subcategory_total_amount, 
           vendor
) T
GROUP BY category,category_total_amount, 
         subcategory, subcategory_total_amount, 
         grp
ORDER BY category DESC, subcategory, 
         CASE WHEN grp<>'Others'THEN 1 ELSE 2 END, 
         SUM(sum_amount) DESC
```

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/qrrlKpKq).

Answer (score 1):

You may use two levels of aggregation with the assistance of `ROW_NUMBER()` function to define unique groups for the other vendors whose their sum of amount is ranked 4 or more as the following:

```
SELECT category, subcategory, 
       CASE grp WHEN 'Others'
         THEN CONCAT(COUNT(*),' ', grp)
         ELSE grp
       END AS vendor,
       SUM(sum_amount) AS total_amount
FROM
(
  SELECT category, subcategory, vendor, SUM(amount) sum_amount,
       CASE 
         WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY category, subcategory ORDER BY SUM(amount) DESC) <=3
         THEN vendor
         ELSE 'Others'
       END AS grp
  FROM purchases
  GROUP BY category, subcategory, vendor
) T
GROUP BY category, subcategory, grp
ORDER BY category DESC, subcategory, 
         CASE WHEN grp<>'Others'THEN 1 ELSE 2 END, 
         SUM(sum_amount) DESC
```

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/YpckAuEe).

In case that there could be more than one vendor with the same top three sum of amount value and you want to list them all (not only three of them) then replace the `ROW_NUMBER()` function with `DENSE_RANK()` function . See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/lAsUpy10) on a modified dataset.

Comment: thank you! appreciate the explanation of different functions

Comment: You are welcome, But I noticed a problem with using the DENSE_RANK, I'm working on it now, I will update the answer soon. For the ROW_NUMBER I think it's OK, you may check and update me.

Comment: Kindly, check the updated answer for using `DENSE_RANK` function.

Comment: What would I do to change "Others" to be dynamic, so it returns how many other vendors there are, so it would be, for example:

2 other vendors

Comment: You could use count within a case expression as this https://dbfiddle.uk/lAsUpy10

Comment: What would it be like using the ROW_NUMBER? Thank you

Comment: Use the second query with ROW_NUMBER instead of DENSE_RANK https://dbfiddle.uk/8XbrQZUV

Comment: You are crushing it, I completely forgot that I'd like the sum amount for each category and each subcategory, is that possible? I know I've asked for so much

Comment: No problem, I think it's possible, can you edit the question to show how the output will be.

Comment: Updated the question with output, thank you